Selective React 18 Migration: Enabling Concurrent features for Specific Stories in Storybook with Cypress Testing
I'm in the process of migrating an app to React 18, but I'm running into a bunch of integration test failures(Cypress to test over Storybook v6) To avoid introducing new test failures while I work on fixing the current ones, I am keen to enable React 18 only for the new stories and the ones that aren’t failing..
So far, I've been adjusting the React version in the Storybook config by
{ reactOptions: { legacyRootApi: true } }
https://storybook.js.org/docs/configure/integration/frameworks#configure
However, it sets react version globally for all stories. Any ideas on how I can tweak Storybook to make this happen just for individual stories?

You cannot have concurrent versions of React running. What you can do however is have two instances of Storybook side by side, one for each framework, and use Storybook composition to combine them into the same UI.
